# Passing a variable from a dynamically created button using onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm dynamically adding a button to a table that has an `onclick` event. The `onclick` function passes a variable as follows:

```
var callId = json[i].sys_id;
```

The button code I've tried (plus variations of the quotes and escaping quotes) is:

```
tr.append("<td><button onclick='getNotes('"+callId+"');'>Details</button></td>");
```

It always comes back with:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Or it doesn't throw an error but doesn't work. If I hard code the variable like this it works:

```
tr.append("<td><button onclick='getNotes(\"00695ef3dbd04f40f20cf209af961995\");'>Details</button></td>");
```

I can't seem to get it to pass the variable correctly,

Comment: Replace the single quote by an (escaped) double quote `'getNotes(\""+callId+"\");'>`

Comment: i think you should write this -->  onclick='getNotes("+callId+")'  (without single quotes before/ after double quotes and that semicolon at the end of your function call)

Comment: Thanks Joschi. That did the trick. I wish I posted my question an hour earlier. Would have saved some headache and aspirin.